# Showing an equivalence relation on a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, monoid

I have difficulties solving this exercise.

Let (M, $\star$) be a monoid. Let $M^×$ $\subset M$ be the subset of invertible
elements in $M$. Define a relation $\mathcal E$ on $M$ by declaring that

$x$$\mathcal E$$y$ ⇔ $\exists$ $z$ $\in$ $M^×$ such that $z \star x$ = $y \star z$
for all $x, y \in M$.
Show that $\mathcal E$ is an equivalence relation on $M$.

I know that in order for a relation to be an equivalence relation, it has to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. However, I don't know how to apply the theorems of my script to this exercise. How do I proceed to solve this?

Comment: your definition doesn't make sense. you quantify over $x$ and $y$ on the right hand side, but you do not on the left hand side. I.e. it is of the structure "two things x and y satisfy formula(x,y) iff forall x, forall y: anotherformula(x,y) holds"

Comment: @N.Beck I just checked but I didn't make a mistake typing. I guess there is one in the exercise then?

Comment: "Linear algebra" tag was inappropriate. I have suppressed it. I have added "monoid" tag instead.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh my bad! Thought it would be appropriate since we covered it in our linear algebra class. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Surely this equivalence relation is meant to be $x \mathcal{E} y \iff zx = yz$ for some $z \in M$ (if $M$ were a group, this would be the conjugacy equivalence relation). Saying "for all $x, y \in M$" is a bit confusing, I think you should delete that part from your definition.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks for your comment. I don't know what the correct version could look like. I typed this verbatim from my exercise sheet. It confuses me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the following slightly reworded version of your posted definition:

  Let (M,*) be a monoid and let $M^{\times}$ be the set of invertible elements of $M$.
  Define a relation $\mathcal E$ on $M$ by declaring that $a{\;\mathcal E\,}b$ if $u{\,*\,}a = b{\,*\,}u$ for some $u \in M^{\times}$.

The goal is to show that $\mathcal E$ is an equivalence relation on $M$.

For convenience of notation, for $a,b\in M$ we'll write $ab\;$to mean $a{\,*\,}b$.

Let the identity element of $M$ be denoted by $1$.

First we show that $\mathcal E$ is reflexive.

  Let
  $a\in M$
  .
  Then $ua=au$ holds using $u=1$, hence $a{\;\mathcal E\,}a$.

It follows that $\mathcal E$ is reflexive.

Next we show that $\mathcal E$ is symmetric.

  Let
  $a,b\in M$
  and suppose
  $a{\;\mathcal E\,}b$
  .
  Let $u\in M^\times$ be such that $ua=bu$.

  Let $u'\in M^{\times}$ be such that $uu'=1=u'u$.

  Then we get
  $$
  u'b
  =
  (u'b)(uu')
  =
  u'(bu)u'
  =
  u'(ua)u'
  =
  (u'u)(au')
  =
  au'
  $$
  hence $b{\;\mathcal E\,}a$.

It follows that $\mathcal E$ is symmetric.

Finally we show that $\mathcal E$ is transitive.

  Let
  $a,b,c\in M$
  and suppose
  $a{\;\mathcal E\,}b$
  and
  $b{\;\mathcal E\,}c$
  .
  Let $u,v\in M^\times$ be such that $ua=bu$ and $vb=cv$

  Let $u',v'\in M^{\times}$ be such that $uu'=1=u'u$ and $vv'=1=v'v$.

  Let $w=vu$ and let $w'=u'v'$.

  Then $w\in M^{\times}$ since
  $$
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{align*}
  ww'&=(vu)(u'v')=v(uu')v'=vv'=1
  \\[4pt]
  w'w&=(u'v')(vu)=u'(v'v)u=u'u=1
  \\[4pt]
  \end{align*}
  \right.
  $$
  Then we get
  $$
  wa
  =
  (vu)a
  =
  v(ua)
  =
  v(bu)
  =
  (vb)u
  =
  (cv)u
  =
  c(vu)
  =
  cw
  $$
  hence $a{\;\mathcal E\,}c$.

It follows that $\mathcal E$ is transitive.

Therefore $\mathcal E$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Wow thank you for this extensive answer! I think I got it now.